# Ckeditor Link Anchor without target _blank?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 7.x-1.x-dev in drupal where I have links defaulted to be set to **target _blank**.

Is there any way to **enable the Target tab for anchor links** so I can remove the target _blank or better even default anchor links to not use target _blank?

Possibly in `ckeditor/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js or anchor.js` ?

EDIT: found in links.js

```
"url"==p?(c.config.linkShowTargetTab&&a.showPage("target"),f||a.showPage("upload")):(a.hidePage("target"),f||a.hidePage("upload"));
```

**How to change it that it shows that tab for both "url" and "anchor"?**

I tried adding it for anchor but then it's not showing anymore for the "url" link type. 
But a default to _self would be far better.

Answer (score 0):

ok I think i managed by adding `||"anchor"==p?` after the `"url"==p` definition, works as desired to show the tab for both link types.

Maybe somebody can confirm / help with how to default it to **_self for just the anchor**?

I have it set to _blank here

```
a.email.body=this.getValue()}}],setup:function(){this.getDialog().getContentEl
ement("info","linkType")||this.getElement().hide()}}]},{id:"target",requiredContent:"a[target]",label:b.target,title:b.target,elements:[{type:"hbox"
,widths:["50%","50%"],children:[{type:"select",id:"linkTargetType",label:g.target,"default":"_blank",style:"width : 100%;",items:[[g.notSet,"notSet"
],[b.targetFrame,"frame"],[b.targetPopup,"popup"],[g.targetNew,
"_blank"],[g.targetTop,"_top"],[g.targetSelf,"_self"],[g.targetParent,"_parent"]],onChange:r,setup:function(a){a.target&&this.setValue(a.target.type
||"notSet");
```